# Regular expression - number without same digit beside

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex, which fits to every number, that is made from 0,1,2 and don't have the same digits beside - 02021 fits, 0122 doesn't fit.
How it can be written?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked one of the online regex testers and evaluators to see how well your regexes works? And do you *really* need a regex? There's a saying along the lines of "I have a problem, I solved it with a regex. Now I have *two* problems". Why did you pick this solution? And what is the actual problem you need to solve? What is the problem this is supposed to solve? Please [read about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and think about how this question might be one.

Comment: I thought about making a loop with every combination, just like `( (01)?(02)?(10)?(12)?(20)?(21)?) *` but it doesn't work in many cases and the number has to have even digits here.. I need this as a correct input checker in a program, this is the easiesty way how can I do it

Comment: If you do not want to accept empty strings then you should change:

`^(?:([0-2])(?!\1))*$` in `^(?:([0-2])(?!\1))+$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with a digit between zero and two. Capture that in a group and check that the following is not the captured value. Capture that in a non capturing group and repeat that.

[`^(?:([0-2])(?!\1))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/tUyAy6/1)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- A non capturing group `(?:`
- A capturing group `(`
- A character range from 0 till 2 `[0-2]`
- Close capturing group `)`
- A negative lookahead `(?!`
- Assert that what is following is not equal to the first capturing group
- Close the negative lookahead `)`
- Close the non capturing group `)`
- Repeat the non capturing group zero or more times `*`
- The end of the string `$`

Comment: I like your non capturing group, it's better than my solution :-) However your regex **does** accept empty string... so you might have to change the `*` in `+`!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(([012])(?!\2))+$
```

tested here: https://regex101.com/r/6vevDl/1